# Existing sentences with numbers auto number one below other within the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the below problem within my excel sheets each cell has the following values below as mentioned.
Example: Cell D2 has sentences with numbered.

1. Login and configure 2.Test User 3. Open Menu 4. Fill up the form
   5.click on the save button

I want the above ones to be sorted within the same cell with numbering as expected below format within cell D2 or neighboring cell E2

1. Login and configure
2. Test User
3. Open Menu
4. Fill up the form
5. Click on the save button

I tried looking for macros, tried auto numbering, split cells, delimiting nothing is working out as expected. Any solution or a way to achieve this within excel would be of great help.

I developed this below vba code Solution what worked out for me

```
Public Sub LoopRow()

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("C2:C10")
c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c, " 1.", Chr(10) & "1.")
c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c, " 2.", Chr(10) & "2.")
c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c, " 3.", Chr(10) & "3.")
c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c, " 4.", Chr(10) & "4.")
c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c, " 5.", Chr(10) & "5.")

Next c

End Sub
```

Using Replace Instead below

```
Public Sub ReplaceParagraph()

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("E2:E4")

c.Value=Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(c.Value, "1.", _
Chr(10) & "1."), "2.", Chr(10) & "2."), "3.", Chr(10) & "3."), "4.", Chr(10) & "4."), "5.", Chr(10) & "5."), _
"6.", Chr(10) & "6."), "7.", Chr(10) & "7."), "8.", Chr(10) & "8."), "9.", Chr(10) & "9."), "10.", Chr(10) & "10.")
WrapText = True
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Your VBA solution works but is inefficient because it replaces each cell value 5 times for a total of 45 changes to your sheet. Try nesting them all into one command: `c.Value=Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(c.Value,"1.",Chr(10)&"1."),"2.",Chr(10)&"2."),"3.",Chr(10)&"3."),"4.",Chr(10)&"4."),"5.",Chr(10)&"5.")`

Comment: Thank you @Engineer Toast I will implement this above, so it works efficiently.

Comment: Hi @EngineerToast I implemented the replace instead of the substitute as suggested it works fine. however, it createsing extra white space in the cell on top is there a way to avoid this.

Comment: I also tried using Trim function it fails to remove those extra whitespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to insert the line feed character #10

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, " 2.", CHAR(10)&"2.").
```

Then click Home > Wrap Text to change its formatting.

You'd have to nest several SUBSTITUTE functions to replace each number.

Comment: Thanks, @Mobus,  your logic helped me in developing a macro which can renumber each cells in excel. I tried directly substitute it failed to work, then I found someone had mentioned to use Replace instead. then I figured we have to use Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(..) instead